# How to fix new tuple-array future warning error

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am getting this warning:

```
getWavesMaps.py:166: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  map.quiver(x[points],y[points],np.cos(np.deg2rad(270-wDir[points])),np.sin(np.deg2rad(270-wDir[points])),
```

but I am not quite sure how to edit the relevant code line:

```
map.quiver(x[points],y[points],np.cos(np.deg2rad(270-wDir[points])),np.sin(np.deg2rad(270-wDir[points])),
            edgecolor='lightgray', minshaft=4,  width=0.007, headwidth=3., headlength=4., linewidth=.5)
```

where x and y are:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(mydata.longitude.values,
                   mydata.latitude.values)
x, y = map(X, Y)
```

and wDir:

```
wDir = mydata.VMDR.values[i, :, :]
```

Comment: What is the value of `points`? I can imagine something like `x[[1, 2]]` causing that warning.

Comment: Yes. You're correct.